# Creating and fill array when dimensions unknown at compile-time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking into binary serialization and deserialization via VBA.

For this, I would need to be able to create and fill arrays of an arbitrary number of dimensions dynamically. For example, let's say you want to do something like

```
Dim sample(0 To 3, 0 To 4, 0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Integer
sample(3,1,1,0) = 12345
```

so create and fill a 4-dimensional array. It's easy if you know the dimensions at compile time of course, but what if you don't?

```
Sub Deserialize()

  ' Dynamic equiavalent of: Dim sample(0 To 3, 0 To 4, 0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Integer
  Dim dimensions(0 To 3) As Integer
  dimensions(0) = 3
  dimensions(1) = 4
  dimensions(2) = 2
  dimensions(3) 2
  Dim sample As Variant
  sample = CreateArrayWithDimensions(dimensions)

  ' Dynamic equivalent of sample(3,1,1,0) = 12345
  Dim index(0 To 3) As Integer
  index(0) = 3
  index(1) = 1
  index(2) = 1
  index(3) = 0
  Call SetArrayValue(sample, index, 12345)
End Sub
```

Is this possible in any way? Or in other words, is there any way to implement the pseuod-functions CreateArrayWithDimensions and SetArrayValue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant solution. `Redim` can not accept variable number of argument. However, if you can limit "arbitrary", you can try something like this:

```
Sub DimTest()
    Dim sample() As Integer
    Dim dimensions(0 To 3) As Integer
    Dim index(0 To 3) As Integer

    dimensions(0) = 10
    dimensions(1) = 20
    dimensions(2) = 40
    dimensions(3) = 70
    index(0) = 1
    index(1) = 2
    index(2) = 4
    index(3) = 7

    sample = CreateArrayWithDimensions(dimensions)
    SetArrayValue sample, index, 12345
End Sub

Function CreateArrayWithDimensions(dimensions() As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim b() As Integer

    Select Case UBound(dimensions)
        Case 1: ReDim b(dimensions(0))
        Case 2: ReDim b(dimensions(0), dimensions(1))
        Case 3: ReDim b(dimensions(0), dimensions(1), dimensions(2))
        Case 4: ReDim b(dimensions(0), dimensions(1), dimensions(2), dimensions(3))
        Case 5: ReDim b(dimensions(0), dimensions(1), dimensions(2), dimensions(3), dimensions(4))
    End Select

    CreateArrayWithDimensions = b
End Function

Sub SetArrayValue(sample() As Integer, idx() As Integer, value As Integer)

    Select Case UBound(idx)
        Case 1: sample(idx(0)) = value
        Case 2: sample(idx(0), idx(1)) = value
        Case 3: sample(idx(0), idx(1), idx(2)) = value
        Case 4: sample(idx(0), idx(1), idx(2), idx(3)) = value
        Case 5: sample(idx(0), idx(1), idx(2), idx(3), idx(4)) = value
    End Select
End Sub
```

An alternative (and more flexible) solution is to use the good old 1 dimensional linear storage concept (just the way the system stores the arrays in fact), and calculate the real position of the actual entry.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping there might be some sneaky way e.g. by creating some SAFEARRAY and memcopy'ing data into it; but that would get super tricky with Variant/String/etc. types as well. Anyways - will go down that route and just limit support to a reasonable number of dimensions! Thanks

Comment: Afterthought - I think I have solved this "in principle" for the general case; I can e.g. create a 1dimensional array, and then create a new SAFEARRAY header with the correct SAFEARRAYBOUND elements, and re-point the array to use this instead. But I have to look into memory management, I'm not sure how VBA handles this and am afraid this might leak (e.g. nothing points to the old SAFEARRAY structure anymore - would it ever be released from memory then?)

Answer (score 0):

How about using a 'dictionary' instead of a multidimensional array. The key could be a concatenation of all indexes.

Add a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` or change this to late binding.

```
Option Explicit

Dim sample As New Scripting.Dictionary

Sub test()
    Dim index(0 To 3) As Integer
    index(0) = 3
    index(1) = 1
    index(2) = 1
    index(3) = 0
    Call SetArrayValue(sample, index, 12345)
    Debug.Print GetArrayValue(sample, index)
End Sub

Sub SetArrayValue(sample As Dictionary, index() As Integer, val As Variant)
    Dim key As String
    key = createIndexKey(index)
    If sample.Exists(key) Then
        sample(key) = val
    Else
        Call sample.Add(key, val)
    End If
End Sub

Function GetArrayValue(sample As Dictionary, index() As Integer) As Variant
    Dim key As String
    key = createIndexKey(index)
    If sample.Exists(key) Then
        GetArrayValue = sample(key)
    Else
        GetArrayValue = Null
    End If
End Function

Function createIndexKey(index() As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    createIndexKey = ""
    For i = LBound(index) To UBound(index)
        createIndexKey = IIf(createIndexKey = "", "", ":") & index(i)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks - good idea in principle. Unfortunately in my case, it does need to be in array form - as this is about serialization/deserialization, I do need to recreate exactly the types that were previously serialized

Comment: In that case you have to go the hard way and use a collection of `Case`-statements. I was working on an example, but @AcsErno was faster.

Comment: Have replied below - thanks for your input as well! I will probably go down that route then!